# how to set specific font family for each locale in jetpack compose

Tags: android, locale, android-jetpack-compose, font-family

In Jetpack Compose, you can set your specific font by editing the `type` file:

```
val MyFont= FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.myfont, FontWeight.Normal)
)

// Set of Material typography styles to start with
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = MyFont,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp
    ),
    button = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = MyFont,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        fontSize = 14.sp
    ),
    defaultFontFamily = MyFont
)
```

But my problem is that I have multiple locales, and I want to set the specific font for each one.

Before using Compose, my approach was to create a `style.xml` file in each language `values folder` and edit the `style.xml` in a way that changes the font family. but this approach won't work when using Compose.

So how can I have a different font family for each locale?

Comment: Put these fonts to the diffrerent font locale with the same name and use in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I didn't get it! Can you explane in more detailed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to achieve this you need to follow some steps as below:

1. These fonts should be the same name and put in the different font locale folder. [image: Put fonts in different folder]
2. Define `FontFamily` with that font name

   ```
   val myFontFamily = FontFamily(
       Font(R.font.lato_light, FontWeight.Light),
       Font(R.font.lato_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
       Font(R.font.lato_italic, FontWeight.Normal, FontStyle.Italic),
       Font(R.font.lato_regular, FontWeight.Medium),
       Font(R.font.lato_bold, FontWeight.Bold)
   )
   ```
3. Use in your `Text`

   ```
   val text = "Hello Android Developers"
   Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp)) {
       Text(text, fontFamily = myFontFamily, fontWeight = FontWeight.Light)
       Text(text, fontFamily = myFontFamily, fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium)
       Text(text, fontFamily = myFontFamily, fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic)
   }
   ```

The result of English and Spanish locale as below:
[image: Text will be in different font in different locales (en&es)]

Comment: I've done this but font doesn't change till application restart, any solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498248/font-resources-doesnt-change-after-changing-locale-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any better approach, but I think can implement it using simple Strategy Pattern.
Create an interface for the `fontFamily`, i.e.

```
interface MyFont {
    fun getBody1FontFamily()
    fun getButtonFontFamily()
}
```

and then implement it i.e.

```
class EnglishFont: MyFont {
   fun getBody1FontFamily() = // font for body1 on English locale
   fun getButtonFontFamily() = // font for button on English locale
}

class KoreanFont: MyFont {
   fun getBody1FontFamily() = // font for body1 on Korean locale
   fun getButtonFontFamily() = // font for button on Korean locale
}
```

Then, in your composable function you can create your `myFont` object based on the locale and inject the object to `Typography`

```
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = myFont.getBody1FontFamily(),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp
    ),
    button = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = myFont.getButtonFontFamily(),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        fontSize = 14.sp
    ),
    defaultFontFamily = MyFont
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But are you sure I can check the locale inside the `type` file? I tried to use `Locale.getDefault()`, but I got a warning, and it seems it doesn't work correctly. Do you have any idea to achieve local?